# Codeigniter shows 500 Internal server error when I reload page

Tags: codeigniter

This happens almost every time, I've tried several `.htaccess` options but at some point it works fine, then the next moment i reload page or click a link

> 500 internal server error

is shown.
The Website is hosted online.

Error Logs show

> [Thu Jun 14 15:05:42.288786 2018] [:error] [pid *****:tid
>   ******] (12)Cannot allocate memory: [client
>   HIDDEN] couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp for /home/sakatadi/public_html/index.php

Comment: check error log

Comment: added Error Log. Please Advice

Comment: Check your server space. Remove unwanted Zip files and images from your server